# Iterating over elements from DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName() doesn't work

Tags: php, xml, dom, domdocument

I have this tiny class that will help me to replace custom tags with valid HTML tags. My issue with it is, it replaces only the first custom tag for whatever reason. My *guess* is that I'm breaking the reference somewhere, but I can't figure out where... Scroll down to the bottom of this post to see the actual result and the expected output.

```
<?php
class DomParser {

    protected $tags = [];
    protected $document;

    public function __construct($html) {
        $this->document = new DOMDocument();
        $this->document->loadXML($html);
    }

    public function addTag(string $name, callable $callable) {
        $this->tags[$name] = $callable;
    }

    public function replace() {
        foreach ($this->tags as $name => $callable) {
            $elements = $this->document->getElementsByTagName($name);

            foreach ($elements as $element) {
                $callable($element, $this->document);
            }
        }

        return $this->document->saveHTML();
    }
}
```

Example code to run the class:

```
<?php
require_once 'DomParser.php';
//require_once 'RenameTag.php';
//require_once 'Container.php';

$html = '<html>
    <container>
        <col>
            <p>
                <test attribute="test" attribute2="this">test<br />test2</test>
            </p>
        </col>
        <col>
            test col
        </col>
    </container>
    <container fluid="test"><test>dsdshsh</test></container>
</html>';

$parser = new DomParser($html);

//$parser->addTag('test', RenameTag::create('othertag'));
//$parser->addTag('container', Container::create());

$parser->addTag('col', function($oldTag) {
    $document = $oldTag->ownerDocument;

    $newTag = $document->createElement('div');
    $oldTag->parentNode->replaceChild($newTag, $oldTag);

    foreach (iterator_to_array($oldTag->childNodes) as $child) {
        $newTag->appendChild($oldTag->removeChild($child));
    }

    $newTag->setAttribute('class', 'col');
});

echo $parser->replace();
```

I'm getting this result:

```
<html>
        <container>
                <div class="col">
                        <p>
                                <test attribute="test" attribute2="this">test<br>test2</test>
                        </p>
                </div>
                <col>
        </container>
        <container fluid="true"><test>dsdshsh</test></container>
</html>
```

The expected output should be:

```
<html>
        <container>
                <div class="col">
                        <p>
                                <test attribute="test" attribute2="this">test<br>test2</test>
                        </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    test col
                </div>
        </container>
        <container fluid="test"><test>dsdshsh</test></container>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you are changing the document structure while trying to iterate over it.

The alternative is to use XPath, which will take it's own copy of the nodes for you to loop over, the changes are fairly small, but will give the output your after...

```
public function replace() {
    $xp = new DOMXPath($this->document);

    foreach ($this->tags as $name => $callable) {
        $elements = $xp->query("//".$name);
        foreach ($elements as $element) {
            $callable($element, $this->document);
        }
    }

    return $this->document->saveHTML();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the excellent answer! It works just fine. But whats the actual problem of modifying the DOM while iterating over it? As long as I don't break the reference (I guess I do that somewhere) it should work? I'm trying to understand the problem.

Comment: I think the problem is that as you replace the `$name` element, you are altering the list of tags with that name, which is also why as the other answers points out, you can sometimes process them last first.

Answer (score 0):

`DOMNode::getElementsByTagName()` returns a "Live" result. The items and the list change as the document changes. You modify the document so the items in the list change as well. Here are tree ways to avoid the problem.

1. You can iterate the list in reverse (using a for loop). Most of the time this will mean that you only change parts of the document that do not affect the previous elements in your node list.
2. Use methods that return a stable result. `DOMXpath::evaluate()` (and `DOMXpath::query()`) return an stable list. Xpath expressions reduce the amount of code needed to fetch nodes as well.
3. Convert the node list into an array using `iterator_to_array()`. This will create an array copy of the node lists with the node objects in it. You used that method in your example code actually.